# Rails: How to produce 404 or redirect upon undesired url exploitation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, http-status-code-404

I want to hide the urls for editing users and their profiles behind safer and meaningful urls. For instance, I want `/user/13/edit` to be `/settings/account` and `/user/13/profile/edit` to be `/settings/profile`.

I managed to achieve that, but for that I had to load the user information from the `current_user` bit from the session. Like so:

```
# users_controller
def edit
  @user = current_user
end

# profiles_controller
def edit
  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.profile
end
```

But now, since I can't compare `@user.id` from the `params` with the `current_user` in the session, how can I stop the old urls (`/user/13/edit` and `/user/13/profile/edit`) from being exploitable? They always load the forms for the current user, so there's no harm done, but I'd be more comfortable if they just produced a 404 error or something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your authentication mechanism needs to set the current user.

routes.rb

```
map.account '/settings/account', :controller => 'user', :action => 'edit' 
map.profile '/settings/profile', :controller => 'user', :action => 'edit_profile'

map.resources :users, :only => [:edit, :update, :show],
              :member => { :edit_profile => :get, :update_profile, :put }
```

this produces the following routes:

```
/settings/account         (get)
/settings/profile         (get)
/users/:id                (get, put)
/users/:id/edit           (get)
/users/:id/edit_profile   (get)
/users/:id/update_profile (put)
```

users_controller.rb

```
before_filter :redirect_if_unauthorized

def edit
  @user = current_user
end

# profiles_controller
def edit
  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.profile
end

protected

def redirect_if_unauthorized
  redirect_to some_path if params[:id] or current_user.nil?
end
```

Obviously some_path does not exist, you will have to create a page/path, etc. to display an error.

With this solution, you never display/manipulate a user based on params[:id], only the current_user saved by your authentication scheme.

---

I might also suggest looking at the declarative_authorization gem/plugin ([Github](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization), [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization))

Comment: My problem is precisely that the new urls don't provide params that I can use for comparison anymore.

Comment: I made some edits, is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried adapting your solution to my code but couldn't get it to work. I'm going to look into the plugin now. Thanks for helping.

Comment: My pleasure, let me know how it goes.  By the way, what was the specific problem you were having with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

the /edit urls still exist because i'm betting you have a map.resources in your routes.rb file for the user model.  you can put a line higher than that in your routes.rb file that matches explicitly the edit lines you are looking to re-route and point them wherever you'd like.